# Mysql trigger for checking duplicate record in Table before insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am to creating a trigger for my table `User` which checks for duplicates (Mobile number) in the *User* table before inserting a new row.

My User table structure is:

```
USERID | FirstName | LastName | EmailID | Mobile
```

I am using the below code to create a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Before_Insert_User
BEFORE INSERT ON User
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM User WHERE Mobile = NEW.Mobile)) THEN
    INSERT INTO User (USERID, FirstName, LastName, EmailID, Mobile,) 
    VALUES (NEW.USERID, NEW.FirstName, NEW.LastName, NEW.EmailID, NEW.Mobile); 
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But this trigger is giving me an error as below while inserting new records:

> Cannot update the user information (Can't update table 'User' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.)

I am not getting where I am doing a mistake.

How can I write a trigger for checking if the value being inserted is already present in User table?

Comment: why not just put a unique constraint on mobile no.?

Comment: @KP. the table was used for a long time, now I am changing it. It has many duplicate Mobile numbers present which can not be removed so i cant apply Unique constraint. Is trigger good approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are thinking about this backwards.  The trigger runs before the insert.  If the code succeeds, then the insert goes ahead.  You need to generate an error if you don't want the row inserted:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER Before_Insert_User
BEFORE INSERT ON User
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM User WHERE Mobile = NEW.Mobile)) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INSERT failed due to duplicate mobile number';
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

However, this is the wrong way to implement this constraint.  You just want `Mobile` to be unique in the table, so use a unique constraint or index:

```
alter table user add constraint unq_user_mobile unique(mobile);
```

Comment: Ya, i had the same idea of making mobile unique, but there are many duplicates already present and we can't remove the so I thought of implementing triggers. BTW the above code is giving error as `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INSERT failed due to duplicate mobile number';   END' at line 6`

Comment: What if you want the trigger to quietly ignore the insert or update if there is a duplicate and not generate any errors?

Comment: @PaulMan . . . Questions should be asked as questions, not comments.

Comment: @PaulMan You should use stored procedures to prevent the insertion, because once insert query is executed, then the only way to prevent the insertion is SQL errors/signals.